# get attribute value from XML using as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to get the value of an attribute `full` where another attribute `name` is equal to something `e.target.name`.

So in this case I am trying to get the value of "full"

```
var full_url = myXML.item.@full.(@name=="e.target.name");
```

This is my XML:

```
<item name="Toy Box" thumb="resize/thumb_image2.png" full="full_images/image2.png" />
<item name="Toy Train" thumb="resize/thumb_image3.png" full="full_images/image3.png" / >
<item name="Toy Truck" thumb="resize/thumb_image4.png" full="full_images/image4.png" />
```

So my as above should return one of the But when I trace full_url I get nothing and no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors in your e4x statement: There should not be quotes around `e.target.name`, and you have to select the item before you can call the value of `@full`.

This should work:

```
var full_url:String = myXML.item.(@name==e.target.name).@full;
```

(that's assuming `myXML` also has a root element somewhere).